# Connecting Raspberry Pi to WiFi from command line

Tags: raspbian, lxde

Does anyone know how to set LXDE to move the mouse cursor with NUMPAD keys?  I've tried all combinations of CTRL + ALT + SHIFT keys that I can think of as well as toggling NumLock setting with SHIFT + NumLock.  Nothing works.  Surely this is something there should be a simple fix for.

I cannot load or update anything as I cannot connect to WiFi without setting that up in LXDE.  And I cannot set up the WiFi (although I can see the right connection in WiFi Config) because the GUI has no way of simulating a double-click on the right network if there is no mouse.  I need the two RPi USB ports for dongle and keyboard, so its a very nice Catch 22.

The frustrating thing is I fixed this exact problem about 6 months ago, but now I can't figure out how I did it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should still be able to setup your Wi-fi from the command line. If you use CTRL-ALT-F1 will switch you to a console terminal. You can then edit /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf to add your network:

```
network={
  ssid="<NETWORK NAME!>"
  proto=WPA2
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
  pairwise=CCMP
  group=CCMP
  eap=TLS
  psk="<NETWORK PASSWORD!>"
  priority=2
}
```

After you add this simply plug in your wireless adapter and it should work. More directions [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/167425/how-to-setup-wi-fi-on-your-raspberry-pi-via-the-command-line/). CTRL-ALT-F7 or F8 should take you back to LXDE.

Comment: Thanks Fred. I tested this and couldn't get it to work, but I suspect I was doing something wrong as I've seen this solution documented in a few places.  In the end I connected via ethernet to my Mac and used [wicd-curses](http://www.raspyfi.com/wi-fi-on-raspberry-pi-a-simple-guide/) to get set up.  I've updated the title to reflect the solution for the benefit of others.